# Why float number get rounded in C but not in JavaScript or Python?

Tags: c

At first, I know the float number under `IEEE754` standard is inaccurate for a decimal number, and I try `0.3 - 0.2` in JavaScript and Python and they got the same `0.09999999998`, but I got `0.1` when I try the following code in C:

```
float a = 0.3, b = 0.2, c = b - a;
printf("%f", c);
```

Is the `printf` function rounded the value? If I want to print the inaccurate number in decimal in C, what should I do?

Comment: They're different languages... they need not have identical behaviour.  `float` in C is likely not the same precision as you have in Javascript or Python... try `double` for starters.  After that it's up to how each one handles rounding, etc.

Comment: By default, `%f` prints 6 decimal places (and rounds).  Your number has is best represented as `0.100000`, so that's what's printed.  If you want to see the 9's in all their glory, request more decimal places in the format: `%.10f` for example.  Interestingly, I get the results `-0.100000
-0.1000000089` printing using your format string and the longer one.

Comment: Why does code do `b-a` or `0.2 - 0.3` to show "I try 0.3 - 0.2"?  The sign differs.

Answer (score 0):

you can do by using this :

```
printf("%0.3f", c)
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: yes I've used it , you can change the precision according to you need by adjusting the value

Comment: So this prints 0.09999999998?

Comment: see the link , I have code in c and one more thing the result will be negative since you are subtracting 02. - 03 , see this link : https://code.hackerearth.com/e70fc6m?key=1b007a3de5f6d157139c2da6904e0173

Comment: The code in the online compiler at code.hackerearth.com shows the result of `%f` and uses `c = a - b`.  That's fine; the result is `0.100000`.  Your code would produce `0.100` (give or take the sign, which I don't care about).  The question is asking 'how can I get `0.09999999998` in C' (and the sign still doesn't matter), and your answer does not usefully address that.  There are several levels of problem.  (1) You aren't printing a dozen decimal places; (2) at least on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.3 and using GCC 6.3.0, the difference shows up as just over, not just under, 0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Not much here to detail why a difference from JavaScript or Python.  Just some C details.

---

In C, the default precision for `"%f"` is 6 decimals places after the `.`.  [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048529/why-float-number-get-rounded-in-c-but-not-in-javascript-or-python/43049805#comment73183109_43048529)

```
int main(void) {
  float a = 0.3, b = 0.2, c = b - a;

  printf("%f\n", c);
  // -0.100000

  // To show to 11 places, use, "%.11f".
  printf("%.11f\n", c);
  // -0.10000000894
```

> If I want to print the inaccurate number in decimal in C, what should I do?

Only print up to so many *significant* digits.

```
#include <float.h>
...
  printf("%.*e\n", FLT_DIG - 1, c);
  // -1.00000e-01
```

---

C details:

Variable `c` is not inaccurate, its value is exact, perhaps `-0.10000000894069671630859375`.  It was prior operations like conversion of `0.3` to `float` and subtraction that are inaccurate.

The *printing* of `c` directs `printf()` to print a rounded value to 6, 11, or whatever number of digits specified.  `printf()` can be expected to print the correct text at *least* up to `DBL_DIG` (e.g. 15) total significant digits for `float/double`.

To print typical floating point values *exactly*, use `%a`  (hexadecimal)

```
printf("%a\n", c);
// -0x1.99999cp-4
```